# Why does data.table get copied when returned from Map

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I understood that `data.table` is not copied when returned from a function. However, in this particular case it does get copied. Can one explain why?

```
dt1 <- data.table(a=1)
dt2 <- data.table(b=1)
dt3 <- data.table(c=1)

address(dt1); address(dt2); address(dt3)
[1] "000000005E20D990"
[1] "00000000052301E8"
[1] "000000001D622210"

l <- list(a=dt1, b=dt2, c=dt3)
address(l$a); address(l$b); address(l$c)
$[1] "000000005E20D990"
$[1] "00000000052301E8"
$[1] "000000001D622210"

f <- function(dt) {setnames(dt, toupper(names(dt)))}
l <- Map(f, l)
address(l$a); address(l$b); address(l$c)
$[1] "000000001945C7B0"
$[1] "0000000066858738"
$[1] "000000001B021038"

dt1
$   A
$1: 1
dt2
$   B
$1: 1
dt3
$   C
$1: 1
```

So it is the last line which is making the copy. However, the following does not make a copy.

```
address(dt1)
$[1] "000000005E20D990"
dt4 <- f(dt1)
address(dt4)
$[1] "000000005E20D990"
```

What am I missing?

**Update**
As everybody has pointed out, `map` or `mapply` is making a copy. `lapply` works in the above case but my actual code needs multiple inputs in the function. My understanding was that all `apply` functions use same code. But it does not seems to be the case.

Comment: `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply` and I believe the copy happens in `mapply`.

Comment: I guess @Roland is right. `l<-lapply(l,f)` doesn't copy. I should add that the use of `Map` is pretty unusual, since there is just one argument and so `lapply` should be preferred.

Comment: I noted in the source `C` code of `lapply` there is the line `if (MAYBE_REFERENCED(tmp)) tmp = lazy_duplicate(tmp);` while in `mapply` the line is `if (MAYBE_REFERENCED(tmp)) tmp = duplicate(tmp);`. Could that be the cause? I'm not expert of R internals, so can't tell for sure.

Comment: You can easily avoid using `Map` or `mapply` if you have objects available in the parent frame. Then use `lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) ...)` and subset objects used in `mapply` using `i` iterator, so `l[[i]]` in your example, potentially more as `mapply` loops over multiple objects.

Comment: If I switch `l <- Map(f, l)` to simply `Map(f, l)`, it seems to work fine. You rarely need to use the return value of `set*` functions.

Comment: You should reword the question since `funcdt<-f(dt1); address(funcdt)` shows same address.  In other words, the problem isn't the function, it's the `Map`

Comment: Thanks @Frank. `Map(f,l) works. But it still makes a copy of the data just not assign it to `l`.

Comment: @imsc please post an answer to your question so it can be considered resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody has pointed out, `Map` or `mapply` is making a copy.